# Alfresco Solr "aclchangesets return status:403"

Tags: maven, alfresco, alfresco-maven

I've created a maven project with **alfresco-allinone-archetype 4.4.0** and I've a clean Alfresco.

Starting the project with *.\run.bat build_start* I'm getting this error from Solr:

```
docker-nutella-acs-1       | 12-Apr-2022 10:54:15.943 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT]
docker-nutella-acs-1       | 12-Apr-2022 10:54:15.958 WARNING [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin Match [Context] failed to 
set property [debug] to [100]
docker-nutella-acs-1       | 12-Apr-2022 10:54:16.137 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
docker-nutella-acs-1       | 12-Apr-2022 10:54:16.144 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application 
directory [/usr/local/tomcat/webapps/ROOT] has finished in [200] ms
docker-nutella-acs-1       | 12-Apr-2022 10:54:16.165 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
docker-nutella-acs-1       | 12-Apr-2022 10:54:16.219 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [126593] milliseconds
docker-nutella-ass-1       | 2022-04-12 10:54:16.841 ERROR (searcherExecutor-7-thread-1-processing-x:alfresco) [   x:alfresco] o.a.s.t.AbstractTracker 
Model tracking failed for core: alfresco
docker-nutella-ass-1       | org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03120000 alfresco GetModelsDiff return status is 403
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getModelsDiff(SOLRAPIClient.java:1181)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModelsImpl(ModelTracker.java:291)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.trackModels(ModelTracker.java:249)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.ModelTracker.ensureFirstModelSync(ModelTracker.java:271)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.lifecycle.SolrCoreLoadRegistration.registerForCore(SolrCoreLoadRegistration.java:110)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.lifecycle.SolrCoreLoadListener.newSearcher(SolrCoreLoadListener.java:44)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.lambda$getSearcher$15(SolrCore.java:2249)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ExecutorUtil.java:229)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
docker-nutella-ass-1       | 2022-04-12 10:54:20.040 ERROR (org.alfresco.solr.AlfrescoCoreAdminHandler@29a5f4e7_Worker-3) [   ] o.a.s.t.AbstractTracker Tracking failed for AclTracker - archive
docker-nutella-ass-1       | org.alfresco.error.AlfrescoRuntimeException: 03120001 api/solr/aclchangesets return status:403
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.client.SOLRAPIClient.getAclChangeSets(SOLRAPIClient.java:169)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.checkRepoAndIndexConsistency(AclTracker.java:326)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.trackRepository(AclTracker.java:303)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AclTracker.doTrack(AclTracker.java:95)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.AbstractTracker.track(AbstractTracker.java:215)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.alfresco.solr.tracker.TrackerJob.execute(TrackerJob.java:47)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
docker-nutella-ass-1       |    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:563)
```

What can it be caused by?

How can it be solved?

Looking forward to a cordial reply,
thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known issue with Alfresco 7.2.0 and the old version of Solr that is bundled within that archetype.

You can follow the steps highlighted [here](https://github.com/Alfresco/alfresco-sdk/issues/635) in order to fix your issue locally for now, whereas for the future releases of the Alfresco SDK a newer, compatible version of Search Services will most likely be bundled.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll follow these steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can have this error when Alfresco webapps don't start properly, then Solr can't communicate with Alfresco, can you put the first error you have when you run `.\run.bat build_start` ?

Comment: Hi,
is GetModelsDiff 403, not 404.
I've created the project from new, I haven't entered customizations yet. I expect it to work with the first start.
The first error is the one I posted above.
I've modified the code on my question for a greater clarity.

Comment: Even when ACS fail to start, don't expect 404 error from Solr.

Try purge the docker volume  `.\run.bat purge` and then and run it again, 

what Java version are you using ?

Comment: I've already tried to clean up the volumes, but it keeps giving the same error.
The Java version I'm using is 11.0.13, compatible with Alfresco 7.2

Answer (score 0):

For Ansible installation, ACS 7.30 Ansible version 2.2.1 :

In order to access solr dashboard, http://10.10.10.10:8983/solr/#/

cat /opt/alfresco/search-services-2.0.5.1/solr.sh

Find the export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dalfresco.secureComms.secret= 1ZiWdC3S/fd5RCDXhAoFFPMWkZYYVrxqZVOaHt9QXd3l

Install add-on modheader in Firefox or chrome.
Add header

X-Alfresco-Search-Secret  1ZiWdC3S/fd5RCDXhAoFFPMWkZYYVrxqZVOaHt9QXd3l

Now try to access the solr URL.